# Error while calling Blueprint Hierarchy in Web 8

Tags: cme, web8

We upgraded from 2013 SP1 to Web 8. While calling Blueprint Hierarchy from CME we are getting this error

> "/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Blueprinting.svc/GetBlueprintHierarchy failed to execute. STATUS (500): System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException".

The full error log in event detail is as follows :

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/15510466
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Blueprinting.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The contract name 'Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Blueprinting' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Blueprinting'.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The contract name 'Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Blueprinting' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'Blueprinting'.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupContract(String contractName, String serviceName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is same error I have faced. Upgrade did not overwrite the file/endpoint.

change lines 42-43 on the ..\SDL Web\web\WebUI\Models\TCM54\Web.config as follows:

```
<service name="Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Blueprinting" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.DeveloperBehavior">
<endpoint name="WSBlueprinting" address="" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.WebHttpBindingConfig" contract="Tridion.Web.UI.Models.Interfaces.TCM.IWSBlueprinting" />
```

It's mostly the same as what exists already, except the `contract` is different along with the capitalization on the `endpoint name`.

**Contract**
Old value - `contract="Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Blueprinting"`
New Value - `contract="Tridion.Web.UI.Models.Interfaces.TCM.IWSBlueprinting"`

**EndPoint** 
Old value - `name="WSBluePrinting"`
New Value - `name="WSBlueprinting"`

or if this is into an https env with https enabled configs, update the configs to be as follows:

Old 2013:

```
<endpoint name="WSBluePrintingSecure" address="" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.WebHttpsBindingConfig" contract="Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Blueprinting" />
```

New Web 8 config:

```
<endpoint name="WSBluePrintingSecure" address="" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.WebHttpsBindingConfig" contract="Tridion.Web.UI.Models.Interfaces.TCM.IWSBlueprinting" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a generic .Net WCF error. Check out this post: http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2010/06/07/wcf-4-0-webhost-failed-to-process-a-request.aspx

It looks like the issue is due to the binding which you selected. Try changing that to netTcp or Http.

Answer (score 0):

The contract specified for Blueprinting service inside %Tridion%/web/WebUI/Models/TCM54/webconfig.xml file was wrong it should be "Tridion.Web.UI.Models.Interfaces.TCM.IWSBlueprinting" instead of "Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Blueprinting" . After changing the contract and restarting IIS problem has been fixed.